# Each loop with return false only shows first result

Tags: jquery

I would like to show a point score and user name for 10 entries (class "horse") on button click, which concatenates the value in an image's alt and title tags, attached to a class "lane" for each entry. If I include "return false" to end the each() loop, this function only shows the value for the *first* entry on each entry. If I exclude return false, all of the values appear on all of the entries. I need help understanding how to display just the value of each entry on the respective entry.

Adding HTML sample by request:

```
<div id="lane10" class="lane">
 <img class="horse" id="car10" alt="James Hinchcliffe" title="560 pts" src="indyNewGunMetal.png"/>
</div>
```

```js
$('.showLabels').on('click', Labels);

function Labels() {
    $('.horse').each(function() {
        var imgTitle = (AJS.$(this).attr('title'));
        var imgAlt = (AJS.$(this).attr('alt'));     
        var fullTag = "<div class='carLabel'>" + imgAlt + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;"
                          + imgTitle + "</div>";

        // show image title
        AJS.$('.lane').before(fullTag); 

        // return false stops the each loop.        
        return false;

    });
};
```

Comment: Your loop runs a callback, i.e. a function, and returning inside a function always halts its execution. Sidenote: start by indenting your code - it makes life a lot easier in the long run, both with debugging and getting people to help.

Comment: what is relationship in html tree between `horse` and `lane` ? Sounds like you need to isolate instances

Comment: An html snippet would help. Somehow you need to specify the `.lane` element to target on each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a predicate instead if you need to use the return boolean of the function you are applying on each element:

```
$('.showLabels').on('click', Labels);
var predicate = true;
function Labels() {
    $('.horse').each(function () {
        var imgTitle = (AJS.$(this).attr('title'));
        var imgAlt = (AJS.$(this).attr('alt'));
        var fullTag = "<div class='carLabel'>" + imgAlt + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" + imgTitle + "</div>";
        AJS.$('.lane').before(fullTag);
        predicate = predicate && false;
    });
};

//do something with predicate
```

This is just an idea, the "false" will always change your predicate to false, instead of "false" you should use whatever condition you need to use there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.showLabels').on('click', Labels);
function Labels() {
$('.horse').each(function(i,val) {
var imgTitle = (AJS.$(this).attr('title'));
var imgAlt = (AJS.$(this).attr('alt'));     
var fullTag = "<div class='carLabel'>" + imgAlt + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;"
                    + imgTitle + "</div>";

// show image title
AJS.$('.lane').before(fullTag); 

// return false stops the each loop.  
if(i==9)      
return false;

});
};
```

Comment: still going to affect all `$('.lane')`. Also return false on last item won't do anything, is at end of loop anyway